# Running Django 1.3 on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, python-2.7

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to get django 1.3 running on heroku. I have been going off of their [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) which assumes the user is using the latest version (1.4) of django. If I follow the tutorial, with the exception of explicitly using Django==1.3 instead of the most recent django version, I get an error when I run `django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .` (note the dot)

Error:
File "/home/my_dir/.virtualenvs/hellodjango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 28, in import_module
    raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")
TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument

It still creates the project and the welcome page comes up on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. If I keep going with the tutorial and push it to heroku I get

ImportError at /
No module named hellodjango.urls

Seems like there is some mismatch between file structure between the tutorial and django 1.3.

Instructions on how to install Django 1.3 would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This '.' option don't work for me even with Django 1.4 i get same error as you did. So i ignored the dot:

```
django-admin.py startproject hellodjango
```

Then i moved all files from hellodjango folder to it's parent folder (that's what Heroku need) and deleted the hellodjango folder.

Followed all steps so i could get the app running on heroku but i got same error as you again, "No module named hellodjango.urls". I solved this removing this hellodjango part from settings.py as i changed the files to a new path so settings.py reflect that change now and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The '.' at the end of the ./manage.py startproject myproject . means start a project "in the current directory"(This feature was added in djago 1.4). In django 1.4 instead of importing from myproject import myapp, you just import yourapp directly. Your apps are not longer tied to your projects.

I found this article online that may help you solve your problem: 
http://bitkickers.blogspot.com/2012/04/djangoheroku-quickstart-for-existing.html